# Does dried milk powder retard yeast growth in bread making

Tags: bread

I have found that when using dried milk powder to soften the crumb on wholemeal loaves that the dough doesn't rise as well, even when using 25% strong white flour to increase the gluten.

Is this because of the milk powder?

Comment: Scald milk to inactivate the enzymes. I have heard this for powdered and caned milk.

Comment: Are you adding extra water to compensate for the dry ingredient? Please post a recipe and method

Comment: Thought that the enzymes were removed during the drying process. There is no shortage of water. I'm working on a 65% hydration

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.
Try souring the dough a small percentage to strengthen the gluten  -more elastic- which should help higher rising

Comment: Bit of an instant kind of guy so souring the dough by which I assume you mean adding a sourdough starter is not an option so I have decided to try Pure Wheat Gluten from Amazon.

Comment: Commercial bakers add a small amount of dry powdered souring agent; try some vitamin C

Comment: Nice idea -  I'll definitely give that a go next time

Answer (score -1):

The dried milk is amplifying the dough with casein protein and fat and removes some of the free water. 
The yeast need the free water. Also the more fat to the dough, the less and slower rise you will notice.

Comment: Probably more likely the fat content. I use skimmed milk powder so no extra fat there but do use about 4% butter, again to soften the crumb. Not sure why the casein would make a difference? There is plenty of free water